Is regression coefficients with standardized variables consistent?
Consider a population in which two random variables, $y$ and $x$, satisfy the following relationship,
$$
y=\beta_0+\beta_1 x+u
$$
where $E[u \mid x]=0$. You wish to estimate the unknown coefficients $\beta_0$ and $\beta_1$, and to this end randomly sample $n \geq 1$ individuals from the population. For individual $i(=1, \ldots, n)$ in the sample, you observe $\left(y_i, x_i\right)$. Suppose that the $x_i$ 's do not all take the same value.
Instead of computing the usual OLS estimators, which we denote $\hat{\beta}_0$ and $\hat{\beta}_1$, you decide to first transform the observed $x$ variable in the following way:
$$
\tilde{x}_i=\frac{x_i-\bar{x}}{\hat{\sigma}_x}, \quad i=1, \ldots, n
$$
where $\bar{x}$ and $\hat{\sigma}_x^2$ are the sample mean and sample variance of $x$, respectively. You then estimate $\beta_0$ and $\beta_1$ by regressing $y$ onto $\tilde{x}$. Let $\tilde{\beta}_0$ and $\tilde{\beta}_1$ denote these alternative OLS estimators.
(a) Show that the sample mean and sample variance of $\tilde{x}$ is zero and one, respectively.
(b) (i) Is $\tilde{\beta}_1$ a consistent estimator of $\beta_1$ ? Explain.
(ii) Derive an expression of the sampling variance of $\tilde{\beta}_1, \operatorname{Var}\left(\tilde{\beta}_1 \mid x_1, \ldots, x_n\right)$.
(iii) Propose adjustments to $\tilde{\beta}_1$ so that the adjusted versions are consistent estimators of $\beta_1$.
I know how to solve part (a). But how to answer part (b)?
My try: The OLS estimator $\tilde{\beta}_1$ can be expressed as:
$\tilde{\beta}_1 = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n (y_i - \bar{y})(\tilde{x}_i - \bar{\tilde{x}})}{\sum_{i=1}^n (\tilde{x}_i - \bar{\tilde{x}})^2} = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n y_i (\tilde{x}_i - \bar{\tilde{x}})}{\sum_{i=1}^n (\tilde{x}_i - \bar{\tilde{x}})^2}$
We know from part (a) that $\bar{\tilde{x}} = 0$ and $\sum_{i=1}^n \tilde{x}_i^2 = (n-1)$, so we can simplify:
$\tilde{\beta}_1 = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n y_i\tilde{x}_i}{n-1}$
Substituting the definition of $\tilde{x}_i$:
$\tilde{\beta}_1 = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n y_i(\frac{x_i - \bar{x}}{\hat{\sigma}_x})}{n-1}$
I don't know how to do the next.

what's your try?

@goldboy I add my try.

When $\hat{\sigma}_x\overset{p}{\to}\sigma_x$, the new slope will just be consistent for $\beta_1\sigma_x$. The rescaling just rescales the estimated slope. The centering of regressor makes the new intercept be consistent for $E(y)$. Using the matrix algebra would simplify the treatment ...

@Math-fun can you write down the answer?

I will for sure come back to this question :-)

You can just invoke LLN by letting $n\rightarrow \infty$ and use Slutsky's theorem to combine with the $\hat\sigma_x$ limit.

@Math-fun please remember. Thank you

... see below as promised, I hope it helps you :-)

Note that
\begin{eqnarray*}
\begin{pmatrix}
\widetilde{\beta }_{0} \\ 
\widetilde{\beta }_{1}%
\end{pmatrix}
&=&%
\begin{pmatrix}
n & \sum_{i}\widetilde{x}_{i} \\ 
\sum_{i}\widetilde{x}_{i} & \sum_{i}\widetilde{x}_{i}^{2}%
\end{pmatrix}%
^{-1}%
\begin{pmatrix}
\sum_{i}y_{i} \\ 
\sum_{i}\widetilde{x}_{i}y_{i}%
\end{pmatrix}
\\
&=&%
\begin{pmatrix}
n & 0 \\ 
0 & n-1%
\end{pmatrix}%
^{-1}%
\begin{pmatrix}
n\beta _{0}+\beta _{1}\sum_{i}x_{i}+\sum_{i}u_{i} \\ 
\beta _{0}\sum_{i}\widetilde{x}_{i}+\beta _{1}\sum_{i}x_{i}\widetilde{x}%
_{i}+\sum_{i}\widetilde{x}_{i}u_{i}%
\end{pmatrix}
\\
&=&%
\begin{pmatrix}
n & 0 \\ 
0 & n-1%
\end{pmatrix}%
^{-1}%
\begin{pmatrix}
n\beta _{0}+n\beta _{1}\overline{x}+\sum_{i}u_{i} \\ 
\left( n-1\right) \widehat{\sigma }_{x}\beta _{1}+\sum_{i}\widetilde{x}%
_{i}u_{i}%
\end{pmatrix}
\\
&=&%
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{1}{n} & 0 \\ 
0 & \frac{1}{n-1}%
\end{pmatrix}%
\begin{pmatrix}
n\beta _{0}+n\beta _{1}\overline{x} \\ 
\left( n-1\right) \widehat{\sigma }_{x}\beta _{1}%
\end{pmatrix}%
+%
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{1}{n} & 0 \\ 
0 & \frac{1}{n-1}%
\end{pmatrix}%
\begin{pmatrix}
\sum_{i}u_{i} \\ 
\sum_{i}\widetilde{x}_{i}u_{i}%
\end{pmatrix}%
\end{eqnarray*}
Such that
$$
\widetilde{\beta }_{0} = \beta_0 + \beta_1 \overline{x}+ \overline{u},
$$
and
$$
\widetilde{\beta }_1 = \widehat{\sigma}_x \beta_1+ \frac{1}{n-1}\sum_i\widetilde{x}_i u_i.
$$
The p-lims, as you wish to have, can then be easily pinned down.
